# Cannot install the packages from dl-ssl.com/android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have uninstall the Android plugin from the eclipse by going to help then about eclipse, then installation details. But when I was trying to install it again. I am getting you cannot install it as it is already installed. But I just uninstalled it, then why I am getting this error-

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.0.20100617-0521]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.0.I20100603-1100]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it's caused by ADT 20 required Eclipse 3.6.2, however your Eclipse package(IDE for Java EE developers) depends on Eclipse 3.6.0. So ADT can't be installed due to dependency conflicts.

The possible solutions could be,

```
Update your Eclipse package to latest that will include Eclipse 3.6.2 or higher.
```

After that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

even I've got the same problem...the simple solution is just extract eclipse again (i.e get a fresh installation of eclipse) and then install the android plugin...I know this is not the way it should be done but it works..